# Swift 2.0 Parse Login

Tags: swift, parse-platform, authentication

So I've been attempting to update my code to Swift 2.0 syntax, but I can't seem to get my Parse login to work. I looked over the documentation changes and added the result block for my login, but I'm getting the error "*'(*, *) throws -> Void' is not convertible to 'PFUserResultBlock?'*"

Here is the line of code:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user,error) -> Void in
                if user != nil {
```

Answer (score 1):

This Code might solve your problem.

```
PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user, error) in
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if error != nil {

                        var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later"

                        let error = error as NSError?

                        if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                            displayErrorMessage = errorMessage

                        }

                        self.createAlert(title: "Login Error", message: displayErrorMessage)

                    } else {

                        print("logged inn")

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showUserTable", sender: self)

                    }

                })
```

Comment: You might want to check your indentation; looks like it didn't copy correctly. To make sure you get code formatting, highlight the code after pasting it in and press Ctrl+K (which will add 4 spaces before your code).

Answer (score -1):

Try this version

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            print("Login Successful")
        } else {
            print("Login Failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the error:  Cannot invoke 'logInWithUsernameInBackground' with an argument list of type '(String, password: String, (PFUser?, NSError?) throws -> Void)'

Comment: I've again tried this piece of code here and it works well with XCode 7.0 and Swift 2. Can you please try cleaning the code (Product -> Clean from the top menu) and also deleting your old derived data (/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData) and try again after restarting XCode?

Comment: Yeah I did that, it still gives me the error.. I have one other error in xcode that says  'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]' in my app delegate, so I'm not sure if that could be related and causing this issue

Comment: Did you also empty your trash after deleting derived data and closed xcode?

Comment: Are you sure you copied and used the code I sent? This error may happen when you use ! instead of ? for PFUser and Error. Can you please check?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using ? for PFUser and NSError

Comment: Can you please try downloading the latest version of Parse framework?

Comment: Just did that, updated my version to 1.9.0 and it still is throwing the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll keep working on it and post an answer when I figure it out.. I'll try solving my other error first to see if this goes away.

Comment: I'm downvoting (and I'm also explaining why I'm downvoting because I hate it when other people don't) because I had this same error, and this didn't work, and I object to the continued insisting in these comments that it's the OP's fault that it didn't work. @Øystein-vaagen's answer worked.